# skipping line while overwriting from one csv to other csv ,keeping row1 intact

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, shutil

Current File:

```
**A.CSV**
A,B,C
0,Animesh,019
1,Shivesh,020
**B.CSV:**
D,E,F
0,Ankit,011
1,Ramesh,021
```

I want to overwrite B.CSV with the content of A.CSV without row 1 of B.csv getting hampered

My b.csv should look like:

```
D,E,F
0,Animesh,019
1,Shivesh,020
```

Example:

[image]

I tried the code:

```
import csv

with open("A.csv", 'r') as f, open("B.csv", 'w') as data:
    next(f)  # Skip over header in input file.
    writer = csv.writer(data,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for line in f:
        writer.writerows(line)
```

But I am not able to do it. Does writerows or csv.writer gives the functionality to skip row 1 and copy it from row 2 to end line

Answer (score 0):

Try This instead:

```
import csv

with open("A.csv", 'a') as f, open("B.csv", 'w') as data:
    next(f)  # Skip over header in input file.
    writer = csv.writer(data,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for line in f:
        writer.writerows(line)
```

"a" mode allows appending to the end of a file.

Comment: no , I wont like to append , I have existing data ..i just want to run over(point to) from line 2 and copy from there..I have added the image description also .plz check